# Proof of Weyl's theorem on semisimple lie algebras in Milne's notes

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-groups, lie-algebras

In [Milne's notes on Lie algebras](http://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/LAG.pdf), part (a) of theorem 5.20 (p52) states:

Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a Lie algebra over $k$. Suppose the adjoint representation $\mathfrak{g}\rightarrow \mathfrak{gl}_{\mathfrak{g}}$ is semisimple, then $\mathfrak{g}$ is semisimple.

His proof goes:

If the adjoint representation is semisimple, then $\mathfrak{g}$ is a direct sum of ideals, and every ideal admits a complementary ideal, so is a quotient of $\mathfrak{g}$. Thus, if $\mathfrak{g}$ is not semisimple, then it has a commutative ideal, and hence a commutative quotient, and hence a 1-dimensional quotient. However, 1-dimensional Lie algebras have non-semisimple representations.

I agree with everything he says, but I don't follow his logic. Why does having a 1-dimensional quotient prevent the adjoint representation from being semisimple?

Comment: Isn't the adjoint representation of a commutative Lie algebra (e.g. a one-dimensional Lie algebra) semisimple, although commutative Lie algebras are not semisimple?

Comment: I think the argument shows that $\mathfrak g$ mod its centre is semisimple, and more argument will then show that $\mathfrak g$ is reductive.  So this should be a criterion for $\mathfrak g$ to be reductive, rather than semisimple (I think).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you are right, this statement is not true. I think he has a copy-paste error here.
In fact, we should read Proposition $6.2$ of Milne's lecture notes, on page $57$. There he shows that $\mathfrak{g}$ is reductive if and only if the adjoint representation of $\mathfrak{g}$ is semisimple, if and only if $\mathfrak{g}$ is a product (direct sum) of a semisimple Lie algebra and a commutative one.

Note: Milne himself has acknowledged the error on his web page [here](http://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/errata.html#LAG): From David Calderbank 
Page 52, Weyl's Theorem 5.20. Part (a) states "If ad is semisimple, then g is semisimple". However, semisimplicity of the adjoint representation is characteristic of reductive Lie algebras (Proposition 6.2), not just semisimple ones. The proof uses more than semisimplicity of the adjoint representation.